# How to set up this 2D Boolean Array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, boolean

so I have to do this problem, but these arrays are confusing me because I’m not sure how to combine a boolean with arrays and then have them properly organized. I know this is a completely incorrect code, but I really don't know what to do. These are the instructions:

**Declare a 2D boolean array of size 5 and 10**

**Fill out the array with true if a random value is 0.5 else false**

**Print number of false in the array**

**Print the array one line per row**

**Print the array indexes one line per row**

**Print only the index of the cells with true value**

```
  public class DoubleArray {

  public static void main(String [] args) {


  double [][] a = new double[10][15];
  int zeroCount = 0;               
  for (int i= 0; i<a.length;i++)
   {                               
      if (Math.random()>0.5)  {

           System.out.println("1" + "\t" + "1");
       }
    else 
    {

        zeroCount++;    // increment
        System.out.println("0" + "\t" + "0");

    }
}
System.out.println("Number of zeros is " + zeroCount);  

}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your program is far away from what you are asked to do. Some hints: why do you declare a 2D array of `double` when it should be `boolean`? Why is the size different from the specification? To work with a 2D array you will typically need nested loops.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer did help you making progress (for example accepting it); or let me know if there is some specific detail you would need more help with.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: you just iterate that array and assign values to each cell:

```
boolean booleanData[][] = new boolean[10][5];
for(int i = 0; i < booleanData.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < booleanData[i].length; j++) {
    if ( if (Math.random()>0.5) {
      booleanData[i][j] = true;
    } else {
      booleanData[i][j] = false;
      zeroCount++;
    }
```

And you use the same kind of looping to print array elements, or do other checks on their content.

Or, using the more simple for each loops:

```
for (boolean[] row : booleanData) {
  for (boolean aBool : row) {
     ... for printing, unfortunately not for assigning values ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Though GhostCat has a great answer already, I decided just for fun to make a basic version of what you're asking for. Here's what I came up with:

```
        boolean[][] a = new boolean[5][10];
        int falseCount = 0;
        String trueIndexes = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){         //For every row...
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){  //For every column...

                 if (Math.random() > 0.5)  {        //Assign values to array
                     a[i][j] = true;
                 }
                 else{
                     a[i][j] = false;
                     falseCount++;                  //For every false value, increase the count
                 }
             }
        }
        System.out.println(falseCount);             //Print number of false values

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){

                 System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");   //Print out values

            }
            System.out.println();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){

                 System.out.print(j + " ");         //Print out indexes
                 if(a[i][j] == true){
                     trueIndexes += " " + i + "," + j + " "; //Add up true value indexes
                 }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println(trueIndexes);            //Print out true values
```

It prints:

```
23
 false false false false true true false false false false 
 true false false true true true true false true false 
 true true false true false false true true false true 
 false false false true true true true false true true 
 true true false true false true true true true false 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0,4  0,5  1,0  1,3  1,4  1,5  1,6  1,8  2,0  2,1  2,3  2,6  2,7  2,9  3,3  3,4  3,5  3,6  3,8  3,9  4,0  4,1  4,3  4,5  4,6  4,7  4,8
```

There are many improvements you can make, such as combining the two `for` loops used for printing the elements, (Hint: Look at how `trueIndexes` is implemented, and remember `"\n"`) but I hope this example gives you some context to help you make your own version.